# How do I make the labels and inputs all the same length?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-5

I am developing a web app using razor pages. I am working on the front end (*.cshtml).  I have added 4 objects. Each object contains a label and two inputs. I want all three items inline. I also want the labels across all 4 objects to be the same length.  Same with the inputs. I have figured out how to make the 3 items show up in a line but I can not figure out how to make the labels across the 4 objects to be the same length. Also is it possible to make them the same length and still remain responsive?

The view currently looks like this image. [image shows labels and inputs as uneven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS0Yl.jpg)

current cshtml code

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3 container">
  <div class="row">
    <div clss="col">
      @* Hub Country Field *@
      <div class="row form-inline">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="HubCountryID">HUB Country</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="HubCountryID" onclick="GetHubCountryDesc()" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.HubCountries," ID ","HUBCountryID "))">
          <option value="" selected disabled>-- Select HUB Country --</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="HubCountryDescID" readonly />
      </div>
      @* Sales Region field *@
      <div class="row form-inline">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="SalesRegionID">Sales Region</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="SalesRegionID" onclick="GetSalesRegionDesc()" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Regions," ID ","RegionID "))">
          <option value="" selected disabled>-- Select Region --</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="SalesRegionDescID" readonly />
      </div>
      @* Market Channel Field *@
      <div class="row form-inline">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="MarketChannelToCustomerID">Market Channel to Customer</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="MarketChannelToCustomerID" onclick="GetMarketChannelDesc()" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.MarketChannels," ID ","MarketChannelID "))">
          <option value="" selected disabled>-- Select Market Channel --</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="MarketChannelToCustomerDescID" readonly />
      </div>
      @* Market Segment Field *@
      <div class="row form-inline">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="MarketSegmentID">Market Segment</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="MarketSegmentID" onclick="GetMarketSegmentDesc()" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.MarketSegments," ID ","MarketSegmentID "))">
          <option value="" selected disabled>-- Select Market Segment --</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="MarketSegmentDescID" readonly />
      </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add css to `label` and `select`.For example:

```
<style>
    label, select {
        width:200px;
    }
</style>
```

result:
[image]